# How to log php artisan calls?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

How do can I log every artisan calls?

Ex:
Logging all the `php artisan serve`, `migration` and `seeds`
and save it to a database?

Comment: What exactly do you want to save in a database?

Comment: All the info on who used/called the command

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you need it but here is it. The easiest way (but not the best) - is to modify "artisan.php" with simple code like this:

```
ArtisanModel::create(['command' => $_SERVER['argv'][1]];
```

just after $kernel var

It mean you have to create new Model and store $_SERVER['argv'] result in it.

Another way (the better one) is determine is your application running in CLI mode somewhere in ServiceProvider